# Manual Bit rate control of video in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I wanted to implement a video quality control in video player in swift.I have used preferredPeakBitRate of avplayer item but I am not able to change the quality of video while the video is playing.I have the manifest file URL that contains different bit rates of video.Kindly suggest me any third party video player that used manual video quality control or tell me how I can achieve using avplayer in swift.